# mapstruct reporting unknown property but as far as i can tell its there

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

I have a fairly simple mapper

```
/**
 * Interface TicketLocationDetailsMapper that allows mapping between DTO and Domain and vice versa.
 *
 * @author Owen Gerig / Dev Team <br>
 *         created on 17 May 2022
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR, unmappedSourcePolicy = ReportingPolicy.ERROR)
public interface TicketLocationDetailsMapper {

    /**
     * Converts TicketLocationDetails domain class to DTO
     *
     * @param TicketLocationDetails domain class
     * @return TicketLocationDetails DTO class. If null provided, would return null as well.
     */
    @Mapping(source = "location", target = "locationId", nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS, nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.SET_TO_NULL)
    com.ticket.dto.TicketLocationDetails TicketLocationDetailsToDto(TicketLocationDetails TicketLocationDetails);

    /**
     * Converts TicketLocationDetails dto class to domain
     *
     * @param TicketLocationDetails domain class
     * @return TicketLocationDetails DTO class. If null provided, would return null as well.
     */
    @Mapping(source = "locationId", target = "location", nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS, nullValuePropertyMappingStrategy = NullValuePropertyMappingStrategy.SET_TO_NULL)
    TicketLocationDetails TicketLocationDetailsToDomain(com.ticket.dto.TicketLocationDetails TicketLocationDetails);

    /**
     * Converts domain class to DTO field. dto only holds id where as domain has full object so this extra mapping is needed
     *
     * @param location location domain class
     * @return location ID. If null provided, would return null as well.
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    static UUID locationToId(TicketLocation location) {
        return location.getId();
    }

    /**
     * Converts location ID param to a new location with its id populated. dto only holds id where as domain has full object so this extra mapping is needed
     *
     *
     * @param locationId id of the location
     * @return newly created ticket TicketLocation object with its id populated. If null provided, would return null as well.
     * @since 1.0.0
     */
    static TicketLocation locationIdToLocation(UUID locationId) {
        TicketLocation location = new TicketLocation();
        location.setId(locationId);
        return location;
    }
}
```

My domain class:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "core", name = "location_details")
public class TicketLocationDetails {
    @JsonView(Views.Summary.class)
    private UUID id;
    private String contactName;
    @JsonIgnore
    private TicketLocation location;

    /**
     * Retrieves {@code contactName}
     *
     * @return contactName
     */
    @Column(name = "contact_email")
    public String getContactName() {
        return contactName;
    }

    /**
     * Sets {@code contactName}
     *
     * @param contactName the {@code contactName} field
     */
    public void setContactName(String contactName) {
        this.contactName = contactName;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves {@code id}
     *
     * @return id
     */
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    public UUID getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    /**
     * Sets {@code id}
     *
     * @param id the {@code id} field
     */
    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves {@code location}
     *
     * @return location
     */
    @MapsId
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    public TicketLocation getLocation() {
        return this.location;
    }

    /**
     * Sets {@code location}
     *
     * @param location the {@code location} field
     */
    public void setLocation(TicketLocation location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

my DTO class:

```
public class TicketLocationDetails {
    @JsonView(Views.Summary.class)
    private UUID id;
    private String contactName;
    private UUID locationId;

    /**
     * Retrieves {@code contactName}
     *
     * @return contactName
     */
    public String getContactName() {
        return contactName;
    }

    /**
     * Sets {@code contactName}
     *
     * @param contactName the {@code contactName} field
     */
    public void setContactName(String contactName) {
        this.contactName = contactName;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves {@code id}
     *
     * @return id
     */
    public UUID getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    /**
     * Sets {@code id}
     *
     * @param id the {@code id} field
     */
    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves {@code locationId}
     *
     * @return locationId
     */
    public UUID getLocationId() {
        return locationId;
    }

    /**
     * Sets {@code locationId}
     *
     * @param id the {@code locationId} field
     */
    public void setLocationId(UUID locationId) {
        this.locationId = locationId;
    }

}
```

errors I receive on mvn clean install:

> [ERROR]
> /C:/CodeRepos/work/github/symphony-tickets/src/main/java/com/ticket/mappers/TicketLocationDetailsMapper.java:[33,48]
> Unknown property "locationId" in result type TicketLocationDetails.
> Did you mean "id"? [ERROR]
> /C:/CodeRepos/work/github/symphony-tickets/src/main/java/com/ticket/mappers/TicketLocationDetailsMapper.java:[42,27]
> No property named "locationId" exists in source parameter(s). Did you
> mean "id"?

but I don't understand the fields are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems to have come about due to class names being the same,
changing the dto to TicketLocationDetailsDto has resolved the issue